# jQuery $each, pass results outside of the function

Tags: jquery, each

How can I get the results using $each outside of the scope:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.action', function() {
    var dataresult = $(this).data("set");

    $.each(dataresult.page[0], function(key, value) {
        //do something here
    });

    //Result needs to go here in this format
    "key": value,
    "key1": value1,
    "key2": value2,



});
```

Does jQuery have something like implode?

Comment: push the key value pair in an array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: @Akki619 thanks but it does not work for me. The next part of the code is $load.("page.php",{ }), and If I place dataresult within {} The error in console is "SyntaxError: missing :"

Comment: why you are putting dataresult within {}. Update question with what next thing you are doing in your code.

Comment: Removing {} worked fine. Thanks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push value in an array like below code.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.action', function() {
    var dataresult = $(this).data("set");
    var arr = [];
    $.each(dataresult.page[0], function(key, value) {
        arr[key]=value;
    });

});
```